# Which query is faster in SQL Server: MIN + GROUP BY or MIN OVER PARTITION BY and SELECT DISTINCT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am dealing with a very slow database compared to the number of rows being ingested on a daily basis. I am trying to create a view to aggregate some values but the execution is timing out.

For SQL Server, which query should be faster?

```
SELECT
    userID,
    sessionID,
    Date,
    MIN(Country) Country,
    MIN(Status) Status
FROM
   SomeTable
GROUP BY
    userID,
    sessionID,
    Date
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    userID,
    sessionID,
    Date,
    MIN(Country) OVER (PARTITION BY userID, sessionID, Date) Country,
    MIN(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY userID, sessionID, Date) Status
FROM
    SomeTable
```

Intuitively I would assume the first one since it has fewer operations to perform. However, I've worked with Oracle before and seemed the second approach was always faster. What should it be for SQL Server?

Comment: Depends on data. All performance questions: try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to test the two different methods, if you really wanted to.

However, there is no reason to think that the `select distinct` method would be *faster*.  After all, it is telling the engine to add a new column to every row and then to remove duplicates.  That seems like it would never be faster than the built-in `GROUP BY`, which does the same thing.  It is quite possible that the two generate the same execution plans, however.

And, `GROUP BY` is one of just a handful of clauses in a `SELECT` statement, and so it a fundamental part of the SQL language.  Using `GROUP BY` makes the intent of the query much clearer.